# Ubuntu 14.04 mdadm issues on boot

Tags: ubuntu, raid, software-raid, mdadm

I have a 14.04 Ubuntu machine which has:

- 2 x SSD in RAID 1 (md0)
- 3 x Sata HDD in RAID 5 (md1)

The machine is set to boot from the md0 device. This machine has been running fine for a month or so, with numerous restarts in between, until today.

Now when it boots up, it starts loading Ubuntu, and outputs "Begin: Running /scripts/local-top"

Then I get the following four lines, which repeat every 15 seconds or so.

```
Incrementally starting RAID arrays
mdadm: CREATE user root not found
mdadm: CREATE group disk not found
Incrementally started RAID arrays
```

There is no way to interrupt this process or get to a command line. I have tried the recovery GRUB option, but it still encounters the error and goes no further. I didn't have a Live CD to boot from at the time.

What does this error actually mean? There is another machine with the exact same configuration which boots fine.

Any ideas on how to get past the error to at least get to a login screen and diagnose further?

Screen shot of the problem is available here:
[image]

Comment: Well it seems like you trashed your `/etc/password`, and `/etc/group` and so the `root` user no longer exists.  Either that, or something else is badly broken.  You are almost certainly going to need to boot off recovery media to fix this one.

Comment: is it degraded? (in normal, non-manually-fixed ubuntu setups [raid1, metadata 0.90 maybe 1.0], won't boot degraded due to a grub bug that is forever ignored), and the result is random, but I haven't seen that one.